# Print date 5 days before in particular format

Tags: bash, macos, date

Im trying to get a particular format of a date that was 5 days ago.Im running bash on MacOS

Currently I have

```
date -v -5d
Wed  1 Jan 2020 09:32:07 EST
```

But the format Im looking for is

```
2020-01-01
```

Looking at some solutions I have something like

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
date -j -f %Y%m%d -v-5d "${DATE}" +%Y-%m-%d
2020-01-01
```

Would this be the most optimal way to do this ?

Comment: Does the line `date -v -5d +%Y-%m-%d` not work?

Comment: Or even `date -v -5d +%F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `date -v -5d` works without providing an explicit input date, so will

```
date -v -5d +%F  # %F is short for %Y-%m-%d
```

You just need to add the desired output format.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print the date with

```
date -v 5d +%m-%d-%Y
# output: 01-05-2020
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't just use `date -v 5d +%m-%d-%Y`?

Comment: I did this, because @JasonStanley also stored his date in a variable. It's totally fine to do it without the `echo`.